How to use realloc to increase account space in Anchor?
Lets say that I have the following account struct for my instruction:
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct IncreaseDataSize<'info> {
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [signer.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        realloc = 8 + /* how can I fetch the <current account size>*/ + 32,
        realloc::payer = signer,
        realloc::zero = false
    )]
    pub data: Account<'info, DataAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>
}

#[account]
#[derive(InitSpace)]
pub struct DataAccount {
    #[max_len(0)]
    pub data: Vec<Pubkey>
}

I have some questions:

Is it a good practice to initialize no space and then keep adding more as needed or should I always allocate some initial space?
I want to increase the account space in 32 bytes from its current space (add more 32 bytes), so how can I know its current allocated space there in the attribute? Is there a way to calculate it in the instruction or e.g. on my client I would have to fetch the account, calculate its size, and then pass it as an instruction parameter #[instruction(curr_size: usize)]?
Considering that I find a way to know the account's current allocated space, would I still need to add the 8 bytes for the discriminator? (I saw it on the realloc Anchor example)

EDIT: This solved the problem:
realloc = 8 + std::mem::size_of_val(&data) + std::mem::size_of::<DataAccount>() + 32

size_of calculates the space allocated for the data types and size_of_val the space allocated for the content on the heap.


It depends on your implementation. Keep in mind that a vector of pubkeys has a maximum length, as each account has a maximum size. However, if you are only adding one pubkey at a time, I would say it is fine to initialize the DataAccount with a size of 8 + 4 (an empty vector is 4 bytes).

I would highly recommend not passing it through as an argument from the client side. You can create a helper function in an impl block below your existing code. 8 for the discriminator and 4 for Vec.


pub struct DataAccount { ... }

impl DataAccount {
   pub fn get_size(&self) -> usize { // adding one element
      8 + 4 + ((self.data.len() + 1) * 32)
   }
}

Then, in your realloc, you can call this:
#[account(
    mut,
    seeds = [signer.key().as_ref()],
    bump,
    realloc = data.get_size(),
    realloc::payer = signer,
    realloc::zero = false
)]
pub data: Account<'info, DataAccount>


You will always need to keep 8 bytes added to the account size, which I have already added at the beginning in the get_size() function.

Note: I'm not entirely following why you have #[max_len(0)], but you should keep the init part of the DataAccount separate from this instruction. Simply set the size to 8 + 4 and set data to an empty vector.

Note on 1: If you will always, at some point, add a fixed number of pubkeys, of course, used a fixed vector size.

I added #[max_len(0)] because I'm using InitSpace to calculate the allocated space for the account instead of doing this manually and so I need to specify the initial space for the vec.
